# Does new lawn/sod need aeration?

Tags: lawn, soil, landscaping

I recently bought a house and am new to gardening and lawn care. Some guys stopped by and asked me if I need "aeration service." I was wondering if I need it for my new lawn/sod. I still don't see the grass coming up yet. It's still dry. I bought my house last winter around November. Could some one shed some light on this question please?

Comment: What part of the world are you in and what kind of grass is it? Also confused when you say you don't see the grass 'coming up yet', what exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Aeration" is where the lawn service folks use a machine to poke "holes" in thick grass sod, in order to let the air and moisture penetrate beneath it.  While a lot of people do this as a regular part of lawn maintenance, I don't believe it is helpful under all circumstances.  If you don't even **have** a lawn growing yet, I can't see how it could be of any benefit to you.

By the way, if your lawn is newly seeded, you need to keep it moist during the germination time for your grass seed or it may never sprout and grow.  So if it is dry, you should definitely get some water on that.  If it has been weeks or months since it was seeded, and you don't see any new growth yet, you may need to reseed.

Edited to add:  Ah, I misread.  Looks like you have sod.  I stand by what I said, though, if it's a new lawn (whether sodded or seeded) it shouldn't need aeration services.

Answer (score 4):

Your question asks about "aeration" for your "new sod/lawn"... did you have a lawn installed already? Sod is basically "insta-lawn" and you would see the results immediately. I have never done aeration on sod lawns I have installed.

My experience is that Aeration is a way to help promote the growth and rejuvenation of older, existing lawns. As mentioned in another answer, it allows the soil to absorb moisture easier (bypassing the "thatch" problem most older lawns have).